# Angular dynamic number of inner observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular 5 service and I want to have an observable that maps a dynamic number of, let's call them, *callers*. Any components injecting this service can get a hold of one observer/subject/whatever, use it to present itself "on" or "off" (true/false, whatever), and when done, just complete. And it can do this multiple times.

My service should also expose a BehaviorSubject which passes through all those values. How would I go about that? Example:

```
@Injectable() class MyService {
  results$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(true);
  callers: any[] = [];

  getSubject() {
    const subject = new Subject();
    callers.push(subject);
    // TODO: Now what? How to tell result$ to listen to this new one too?
    subject.finally(() = {
      // TODO: Now what? How to kick it out of the array when complete, and tell results$?
    });

    return subject;
}
```

**Edit:** per comment request, here's an example, a typical consumer would do something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: '<button (click)="doWork()">Do work</button>'
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private myService: MyService,
              private otherService: OtherService
  ) {}

  doWork() {
    // grab the semaphore instance
    const semaphore = myService.getSubject();
    // Kick off the semaphore and start some async activity (http call in my case)
    semafore.next('on');
    otherService.doAnotherWork()
      .subscribe(() => semaphore.complete());
  }
}
```

As you can see, the other service can do two things that matter here:

1. Kick off this semaphore at any time.
2. Kick off multiple at once.

And I can have more than one such consumer at the same time on the page.

(Now that I thought of that, I probably should account for some cleanup logic, such as user navigating away while midprocess.)

Comment: Could you show the `myService`'s consumers code as well, so it makes more sense what the context is and what the "contract" looks like?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Added the example, thaanks for your time and any suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. The usage example helps understanding what you're trying to achieve. I do not see a straightforward way to get what you want using the available rxjs operators only. I will try to write a custom operator and share it with you if I succeed. You've posted a great question by the way.